# How to correctly animate transformations on an priorly transformed UIView

Tags: ios, swift, animation, transform, cgaffinetransform

### **Summary of the issue**

**Unable to correctly perform a move-and-scale animation on an already translated `UIView`.**

When the view has not been priorly moved, in order to achieve the desired result, I apply the **scale first and then the translation**. I animate the resulting transformation using a `UIViewPropertyAnimator`: the View scales up or down whilst moving at the same time accordingly.

However, if the view has been moved (translated) from its original position before applying this animated transformation, *I failed to achieve the result consisting in **scaling up or down whilst moving the View from its new position**.*

*¡**Although transform issues are well documented - and I have done my due diligence before submitting the question - I have failed to find a successful solution so far**!*

### Transformation Animation Code

*In order to facilitate the understanding as well as the resolution of the issue, the codes have been simplified.*

```
extension UIView {

   func zoomAndMove(vector: CGPoint, scale: CGPoint){
      self.transform = self.transform.concatenating(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale.x, y: scale.y).concatenating(CGAffineTransform(translationX: vector.x, y: vector.y))
   }


   func animateZoomAndMove(from origin: CGPoint, for duration: TimeInterval, cameraZoom: CGPoint, timingFunction: UITimingCurveProvider, controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 0.8, y: 0.7)) autoplay: Bool = false) -> UIViewPropertyAnimator {
      let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: duration, timingParameters: timingFunction)
      let vector = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX - origin.x, y: self.frame.midY - origin.y)

      animator.addAnimations {
         self.zoomAndMove(vector: vector, scale: cameraZoom)
      }

      if autoplay { animator.startAnimation()}
      return animator
   }
}
```

### Attempts so far

I have tried to modify my code to return a transform that takes into account a previous translation before the `zoomAndMove` occurs:

```
extension UIView {

   func zoomAndMove(vector: CGPoint, scale: CGPoint){

      if self.transform == CGAffineTransform.identity {
          self.transform = self.transform.concatenating(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale.x, y: scale.y).concatenating(CGAffineTransform(translationX: vector.x, y: vector.y)) 
      } else {
          let preTransform = self.transform
          self.transform = CGAffineTransform(a: scale.x, b: 0, c: 0, d: scale.y, tx: vector.x + preTransform.tx, ty: vector.y + preTransform.ty)
      }
   }
```

This code **does not result in the desired effect**: the view **jumps** to a new location, scales correctly and moves "randomly".

I am definitely missing something - I might be aiming at the wrong end result matrix - but all in all I am currently stuck.

Should anyone have a clue on how to perform such a simple task as ***scaling and moving a UIView from an already translated UIView***, I would be most grateful for their input!

Best,

---

### EDIT

A picture can be worth a 1,000 words, so here is what happens when I try to implement the various suggestions that have been kindly made so far (in particular the `.scaledBy(:)` method):

[image]

You can notice the final transformation is right, but the animation is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, thanks to @gmogames for taking the time to offer suggestions. It always helps to be able to exchange ideas!!!

The issue had indeed something to do with resetting the anchorPoint (or the center) of the view before applying the new transformation so that the animation runs correctly. Therefore, using a much simpler example of **scaling a view after having moved it**, here is what the new method looks like:

```
extension UIView {
    func scaleView(scaleFactor: CGPoint, duration: TimeInterval) {
        // store the view original center
        let oCenter = self.center

        // get the current transformation
        let cTransform = self.transform

        // set the new center of the view 
        self.center = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)

        // clears the transform matrix from potential prior translation
        // Note that you need to take into account potential prior scale of the view into the translation vector!!
        self.transform = self.transform.translatedBy(x: -cTransform.tx / cTransform.a, y: -cTransform.ty / cTransform.d)


        // Animates the transformation
        let animator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: duration, timingParameters: UICubicTimingParameters(controlPoint1: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), controlPoint2: CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1))
        animator.addAnimations {
            self.transform = self.transform.scaledBy(x: scaleFactor.x, y: scaleFactor.y)
        }
        // resets the View to its original center and apply the transformation so that the view stays in the right end position
        animator.addCompletion { (position) in
            if position == UIViewAnimatingPosition.end {
                self.center = oCenter
                self.transform = cTransform.scaledBy(x: scaleFactor.x, y: scaleFactor.y)
            }
        }
        animator.startAnimation()
    }
}
```

Here the result in animation: **move + scale + scale + revert to original**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried assigning the current transform to a property, then modifying this copied property and then re-assigning to the view?
something like:

```
let originalTransform = view.transform
let scaledTransform = originalTransform.scaledBy(x: 0.2, y: 0.2)
view.transform = scaledTransform
```

I have created an animation of a button using this method and it did work fine, but I'm not sure it's what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks @gmogames! I have uploaded a gif to better show the issue. The final transformation is right with your solution, but the animation is not.

Comment: @Chris out of curiosity, if on the second run (the one that glitches) you only do scale, or only translationX, does it glitch? or the glitch only happens when combining those?

Comment: I do both, but for the sake of debug, I have tried translation only and scale only. The issue occurs when applying the scale.

Comment: @Chris what I can think of is, a scale is anchored to the views center. So the final scale on that animation you provide is actually the center where the smaller square was. Maybe you need to update the anchor point of the layer before scaling it again.

Comment: You could also try using the UIView.animate() mode instead of the UIViewPropertyAnimator. I remember there was a nice simple tutorial on https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/15/4/transform-cgaffinetransform

Comment: I think so too and I have already tried to reset `view.center` with the transformed frame, but it does not work. When a transform is applied, the frame changes but not the center. However when you change the center, the frame changes. I have not found the right way to correctly set frame and center with the result of the transform. As regards `UIView.animate`, it might get deprecated soon. iOS seems to go towards `UIViewPropertyAnimator` or good old `CAnimation`, therefore I'd rather not use that method.

Comment: I did also try to set the anchor point using an extension. No luck either :/